# How to add a asp-page-handler dynamically to a <a></a> tag in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

bool result=true;

if the `result` is `true` then:

```
<a asp-route-pageIndex="1">1</a>
```

if the `result` is `false` then:

```
<a>1</a>
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
@{ 
   //just for illustration
    var result = true;
    var pageIndex = 1;
}
@if (result)
{
    <a asp-route-pageIndex="@pageIndex">@pageIndex</a>
}
else
{
    <a>1</a>
}
```

Comment: somehow you need to distinguish.